# Erin Moran nickname in Happy Days

Tags: character

I’m looking for the nickname actress [Erin Moran](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erin_Moran)  (Joanie) was given in the TV series “Happy Days”.

In the Italian version she was called “[sottiletta](https://www.corriere.it/spettacoli/17_aprile_24/sola-povera-morta-joanie-sottiletta-happy-days-45e48f92-2848-11e7-b6aa-7d1d46c4746d.shtml)” but I can’t find the original nickname.

Comment: Do you mean the nickname of the actress herself, or the nickname of the character she was playing? The second one would be on-topic, the first one would not be.

Comment: The second one. Fonzie always referred to her as “sottiletta”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joanie_Cunningham), Fonzie's nickname for Joanie in the original English-language version of the show was "Shortcake". [Shortcake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcake) is very sweet and delicate, so presumably, by calling her that, Fonzie was ascribing those qualities to Joanie.

Incidentally, [a quick Google search](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/italian-english/sottiletta) tells me that "sottiletta" is an Italian term for processed cheese slices. Doesn't seem like the most accurate translation to me.

Comment: I don't think the translation is all that bad.  As a nickname "shortcake" also references how short Joanie is.  It seems that '-etta' is a suffix used in Italian to indicate a smaller than usual version of something and 'sottile' can mean 'slender'.  So it's purely a reference to her size and the connection to the cheese product adds a little humour.  Nicknames don't need to be accurate in every respect (see 'half-pint' from Little House on the Prairie) and there might not be an option that combines both the reference to small size and sweetness in Italian.